# GVim under win7 <leader> key doesn't work

Tags: vim

Searched around but couldn't find any question that share same symptom with mine:

Fresh installed GVim under win7, installed EasyMotion with default setting. Thing is the  key never worked, it always give the beep when I press "\". So I map it to other key like this:

```
let mapleader = ";"
```

But still when press ";" key, it only give the beep and no other response, I'm almost give up after 2 hours...

Comment: Problem Solved: The reason why EasyMotion wasn't wake up was due to my wrong installation. Instead of copy the whole un-zipped folder's content into vim's plugin folder, I picked up the individual file "EasyMotion.vim" which cause the problem.

After I delete the single file, and copy the whole EasyMotion folder into vim's plugin folder, it works great:) cheers~~

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but your mapleader is <kbd>;</kbd> (semicolon) and you say that you are typing <kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

I have

```
let mapleader=","
nmap ,p "*p
```

(and a bunch more maps).  When I type <kbd>,p</kbd> I get clipboard paste.

Another thought would be to unistall gvim, unistall EasyMotion and reinstall gvim without EasyMotion (not sure what that is).

Comment: Thanks buddy, that clipboard paste tip is really cool, and works, well that easymotion still cannot be woken up by <leader>, next I guess I'll have to do some backup and try to re-install them.

Comment: Another clipboard option is to use the [option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'clipboard') `set clipboard=unnamed`. This will make vim use the `*` register for regular yank/delete operations.

Comment: Any idea how to map "Copy to Clipboard" as a shortcut key as counter-part to "Paste from Clipboard"? e.g. I'm in visual mode and highlighted a block of text, and want to copy it to win7's clipboard.

Comment: Copy to clipboard is <kbd>"*y</kbd> -- I have it mapped to <kbd>,y</kbd>.  (Do you mind clicking the "check-mark" to accept this answer?)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why EasyMotion wasn't wake up was due to my wrong installation. Instead of copy the whole un-zipped folder's content into vim's plugin folder, I picked up the individual file "EasyMotion.vim" which cause the problem.

After I delete the file, and copy the who EasyMotion folder into vim's plugin folder, OMG, it just worked:) cheers~~